# How to use Multiple View with routing using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api

I want to use multiple controller using routing concept of `angularjs`but i am getting as below error.

**Error:**

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$injector/unpr?p0=%24windowsProvider%20%3C-%20%24windows
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:2585/Scripts/angular.min.js:6:450
    at http://localhost:2585/Scripts/angular.min.js:36:202
    at Object.c [as get] (http://localhost:2585/Scripts/angular.min.js:34:305)
    at http://localhost:2585/Scripts/angular.min.js:36:270
    at c (http://localhost:2585/Scripts/angular.min.js:34:305)
    at d (http://localhost:2585/Scripts/angular.min.js:35:6)
    at Object.instantiate (http://localhost:2585/Scripts/angular.min.js:35:165)
    at http://localhost:2585/Scripts/angular.min.js:67:419
    at link (http://localhost:2585/Scripts/angular-route.js:910:26) <div data-ng-view="" class="ng-scope">
```

**My try:**

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<html leng="en" data-ng-app="@ViewBag.InitModule">
```

**index.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    ViewBag.InitModule = "homeIndex";
}
@section Scripts{
    <script src="../Scripts/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/home-index.js"></script>
}
<div data-ng-view=""></div>
```

**home-Index.js**

```
var module = angular.module("homeIndex", ['ngRoute'])

module.config(function ($routeProvider) {        
    $routeProvider.when("/", {
        controller: "homeIndexController",
        templateUrl: "/templates/AccountTypeView.html"
    });
    $routeProvider.when("/add", {
        controller: "newAccountTypeController",
        templateUrl: "/templates/addAccountType.html"
    });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });
});
//homeIndexController
function homeIndexController($scope, $http) {
    //homeIndexController code which is working fine
}
//newAccountTypeController
function newAccountTypeController($scope, $http, $windows) {
    $scope.newAccountType = {};
    $scope.save() = function () {
        alert($scope.newAccountType.name);
    };
}
```

**addAccountType.html**

```
<h3>Add New AccountType</h3>
<form name="AddAccountType" novalidate data-ng-submit="save()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">AccountType</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="newAccountType.name" required />
        <span class="has-error" data-ng-show="AddAccountType.name.$error.required">*</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

When I am calling `homeIndexController` controller then it is working fine but when i and trying to call `newAccountTypeController` then i am getting error as above.

As i know it is not big error but I am new with `angularjs`. to solve it i did lots of google and i got lots of answer also but unable to solve. So if someone have solution of this problem then help me any suggestion will be accepted. Thanks it advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you that angular couldn't find the service you are injecting on your controller, named `windowsProvider`.

Maybe you meant `$window`?

```
function newAccountTypeController($scope, $http, $window) {
    $scope.newAccountType = {};
    $scope.save = function () {
        alert($scope.newAccountType.name);
    };
}
```

By the way, you had an error on your `save` function definition...

EDIT: 'unpr' stands for Unknown Provider. Yes I know, super verbose right ?